# Only load backbone view for specific pages

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an application with multiple Backbone models / views. I'm running into an issue where the application tries to load all of the scripts on every page, however I only need them to load on specific pages.

What is the correct way to address this? Should I use a router?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to organize your application code into small modules (require.js). Here is a brief introduction [Organize your backbone application using modules](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/). Load only modules that are required in current page. For details about requirejs [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).
You can use routers in combination to decide which modules of your application to load.